# Ошибка в запросе laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.7

почему при такой выборке

```
$managers = DB::table('managers')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'managers.manager_id')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributs', 'user_attributs.user_id', 'managers.manager_id')
            ->leftJoin('manager_accounts', 'manager_accounts.manager_id', 'managers.manager_id')
            ->select('user_attributs.avatar','user_attributs.fullname', 'users.id',DB::raw('count(manager_accounts.id) as count_m'))
            ->where('managers.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->groupBy('user_attributs.fullname')
            ->get();
```

выдает такую ошибку

> QLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'extremje_insta.user_attributs.avatar' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select
>   `user_attributs`.`avatar`, `user_attributs`.`fullname`, `users`.`id`,
>   count(manager_accounts.id) as count_m from `managers` left join
>   `users` on `users`.`id` = `managers`.`manager_id` left join
>   `user_attributs` on `user_attributs`.`user_id` =
>   `managers`.`manager_id` left join `manager_accounts` on
>   `manager_accounts`.`manager_id` = `managers`.`manager_id` where
>   `managers`.`user_id` = 6 group by `user_attributs`.`fullname`)

Comment: Вы используете группировку по полю ```user_attributs.fullname``` а в выборке указываете поля не участвующие в группировке. По этому бд и ругается. По умолчанию в MySQL ```SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';```. Можно этим запросом ```SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));``` отключить такое поведение

Answer (score 0):

У Вас ошибка  sql_mode=only_full_group_by . Т.е вы делаете группировку, но не используете агрегирование либо группировку на все поля, которые выводите.

Есть несколько решений:

1) Отключить  only_full_group_by. Вот есть ответы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by .

2) Сделать группировку по всем полям, которые вы select . Т.е. как то так:

```
$managers = DB::table('managers')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'managers.manager_id')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributs', 'user_attributs.user_id', 'managers.manager_id')
            ->leftJoin('manager_accounts', 'manager_accounts.manager_id', 'managers.manager_id')
            ->select('user_attributs.avatar','user_attributs.fullname', 'users.id',DB::raw('count(manager_accounts.id) as count_m'))
            ->where('managers.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->groupBy('user_attributs.fullname')
            ->groupBy('user_attributs.avatar')
            ->groupBy('user_attributs.fullname')
            ->groupBy('users.id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: если я добавляю в группировку все поля из select то не выводит ничего